# Alternatives to Rhythmbox to record Streaming Audio

Tags: sound, 13.04, rhythmbox, banshee, streaming

I always have been able to record streaming radio using Rhythmbox, until now. As already reported, there is a bug with 13.04. I tried Banshee. There is also a bug with that, which has been reported. Is there any audio player out there that can record internet radio and make each song an .mp3?

I have tried VLC (can make one file as far as I can tell), Streamripper2, Clementine and Audacious. Streamripper2 works but does not have the stations I want. I really like 13.04, except for this issue. It is faster than 12.10 and 12.04 and I had no issues installing the video card driver, so my preference is to stay with 13.04.

I seem to have hit a dead end on various websites looking for an alternative.  Does anyone have an idea?  Much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Audio-recorder** is exactly what you want.

From it's [launchpad entry description](https://launchpad.net/audio-recorder):

> This amazing program allows you to record your favourite music and
>   audio to a file. It can record audio from your system's soundcard,
>   microphones, browsers, webcams & more. Put simply; if it plays out of
>   your loudspeakers you can record it.

Note that it does not record via a microphone or anything like that.  Rather, it saves the data as it passes through your soundcard!

Audio-recorder is  quite powerful.  You can have it start/stop recording when audio data starts/stops flowing through your soundcard:

> It has an advanced timer that can:
>   * Start, stop or pause recording at a given clock time.
>   * Start, stop or pause after a time period.
>   * Stop when the recorded file size exceeds a limit.
>   * Start recording on voice or sound (user can set the audio threshold).
>   * Stop or pause recording on "silence" (user can set the audio threshold and delay).

Suppose you have Audio-recorder start/stop recording on sound/silence.  If you leave an internet radio streaming all day, then at the end of the day each song will be saved to a separate file.  (assuming consecutive songs are not "mixed")

Installation:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:osmoma/audio-recorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audio-recorder
```

Comment: Yes!  Sorry for the delay responding.

Comment: This program does not work with 14.04 LTS.  This latest release has been a huge disappointment to me on so many levels.  Ubuntu didn't do a great job this time around.  Could this be an issue with audio-recorder?  It worked well with 12.04.

Comment: it's not in the repository for 14.04?  I'm sorry, I am not a pro with Ubuntu or Linux.  Sounds like all the recent distribution versions are bad.  I have 13.04 (raring) and it worked for me.  I guess the owner of the repositroy, "osmoma", is responsible for keeping it up to date with 14.04.  Maybe post an issue/ticket on the repository page

Comment: I tend to think it is the program as I have the same issue with Opensuse 13.1 (I dual boot with Ubuntu).  I gave Amarok a try.  Not perfect, but it seems better than nothing.

Answer (score 6):

#### Command line with [ffmpeg](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ffmpeg) [image: Install ffmpeg] / [avconv](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avconv) [image: Install avconv]

We can save internet audio streams to disk with the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i <IP>:<port> <filename>.mp3
avconv -i <IP>:<port> <filename>.mp3
```

Replace `<IP`> with the Internet address of your station and `<port>` with the port they are streaming. The applications will convert the stream to any known format given by the resulting filename's extension (`.mp3` will write mp3 files, `.ogg` will write Ogg Vorbis files).

Example for a recording of [Gold FM Radio via internet.radio.com](http://www.internet-radio.com/station/goldfm/):

```
ffmpeg -i http://uk2.internet-radio.com:30092 recording.mp3
```

<sup>Radio station IPs and ports may change so the above link may not always work</sup>

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.   I don't think that will make each song an individual mp3.

Comment: avconv works on ubuntu 14!

Answer (score 0):

Try Amarok.

> Amarok is a powerful music player for Linux and Unix, MacOS X and
>   Windows with an intuitive interface. It makes playing the music you
>   love and discovering new music easier than ever before - and it looks
>   good doing it!<sup>1</sup>

To download Amarok, check out their [website](http://amarok.kde.org/en/releases/2.7.1)

Or, to download and install click the image below.

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/en/releases/2.7.1)</sup>

Comment: Can it make individual mp3's like Rhythmbox?  I was under the impression that Clementine and Amarok were quite similar.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean Make MP3's?

Comment: Rhythmbox will make each song an individual mp3 with the Radio-Browser plugin.  Banshee has a similar feature.  VLC will record the entire stream into one file (as far as I can tell).  Does Amarok do that?

Comment: From what I read I think it can, but I can't verify 100%